# How to update Map inside a List

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

If I have a immutable list like:

```
List([
    Map({ something: 1 }),
    Map({ something: 2 }),
])
```

How can I do set something = 5 where something = 1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/map) + [set](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/set) in order to achieve that

```js
console.clear();

const list = Immutable.List([
    Immutable.Map({ something: 1 }),
    Immutable.Map({ something: 2 }),
    Immutable.Map({ something: 4 }),
    Immutable.Map({ something: 1 })
])


const newList = list.map(item => 
    item.get("something") === 1 ? item.set("something", 5) : item
);

console.log('Old',JSON.stringify(list.toArray(),null, ""));
console.log('New',JSON.stringify(newList.toArray(),null, ""));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.7.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Qop's answer will work great if you are looking for a specific key.

If you want to update multiple values in each Map, you could use [.mapEntries()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection.Keyed/mapEntries) inside the list.map call.

```
things
    .map(thing => {
      return thing.mapEntries(([ k, v ]) => {
        const val = (v === 5) ? 1 : v;
        return [ k, val ]
      })
    });
```

[here is a link to working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WiP0uy?p=preview)